# Column Chart and Nplot with C#

Tags: c#

I am currently developing an application in C# using the NPlot Charting Library.

I want to have a 2 bar charts side by side for each label across the X axis instead of them being stacked on top of each other.

Is this possible with Nplot, I couldn't find anything on Google but the Nplot documentation implies that you can have them side by side instead of stacked.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out you change the bases offset i.e.

```
HistogramPlot myPlot = new HistogramPlot();
myplot.baseOffSet = 0.3f
```